# How to save the items that a user bought in the database and prevent him to buy it again

Tags: php, mysql, field, store

I need some help storing the files a user bought and downloaded. I have a table with files and their ID. When users buy and file it's just redirecting him to the download link. But I want to make PHP script insert into the database the ID of the files that user bought. But how to do it with multiple files and store their ID in 1 field for each user. For example I have 10 files and the user bought files 1,2,3,8,9. I want to store in the database these numbers and do a while to show the link that corresponds to these ID's.

Comment: You're essentially asking "how do I use a database in PHP?"  There are many tutorials and examples to get you started.  (Admittedly the quality of any given tutorial is a shot in the dark, but that's why it's advisable to use a variety of different tutorials to broaden your introduction to the technology.)  You are encouraged to start there and to begin attempting to build your functionality.  (As a hint, consider creating a table with a foreign key to the users and a foreign key to the files, and inserting records into that table.)  If you encounter a specific problem, we can help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a table `user_files` that has two columns, `user_id` and `file_id` forming a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE user_files (
  user_id         INT NOT NULL,
  file_id         INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, file_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files(id),
);
```

If user `1` buys files `1,2,3,8,9`, you would then do

```
INSERT INTO user_files (user_id, file_id) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,8), (1,9)
```

and then, when you need to check if a user has bought you just check if that user_id / file_id combination exists in the table.